# What prevents water from getting underneath these roof shingles?

Tags: roof, shingles

I see a lot of houses In my area with roof edges where one side of shingles overlaps the other. For example:

[image]

Is anything special needed to prevent water from getting underneath the overlap?

Comment: Protip: steel valley flashing is much better if you have trees depositing their goodies on your roof. Lapped valleys have enough friction that debris likes to accumulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are several things required to make a “valley” installation waterproof.

There are two ways to install valley shingles: 1) “open cut”, and 2) “closed cut”.

Here’s an illustration of each:

[image]

[image]

http://esgreenville.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/timberlineinstallation.pdf

You have the “closed cut” system.

Answer (score 1):

> Is anything special needed to prevent water from getting underneath
>   the overlap?

Gravity... water doesn't flow up hill...

Comment: That's all there is to it, just like with conventional metal valley flashing (and literally every shingle on the roof).

Comment: @isherwood We know shingles leak, that’s why underlayment paper is required. For valleys, there’s a double layer required...the manufacturer’s do not rely just on gravity.

Comment: Yes, but that underlayment exists under _any_ valley style, and only as a safety measure in the case of ice dams, etc. It's irrelevant here in a discussion of shingling technique.

Comment: @JRaef Actually Water does flow up hill on buildings due to driving wind and wind pressure.